# JavaScript's 'forEach' misunderstanding

Tags: javascript

This function works properly:

```
function task02(arr) {
  var out = [];
  arr = arr.forEach(function(item, i){
    (item > 0) ? out.push(1) : out.push(0);
  });
  return out;
}
```

And this one's not (outputs `undefined`):

```
function task02(arr) {
  arr = arr.forEach(function(item, i){
    (item > 0) ? item = 1 : item = 0;
  });
  return arr;
}
```

I've tried using both `item` and `item[i]`, but it's not working. Can someone please explain to me, why this is not working?

Comment: `item` hold the value of `arr[i]`, so you cannot change the original value like this.

Comment: So, replacing `item` with `arr[i]` must work?

Comment: Nah, it's not working.

Comment: It's because you do `arr = arr.forEach` and `forEach` return nothing, you have to remove the assignment `arr =`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback function in your second example doesn't have any side-effects. It just iterates over the array, does the comparison and that's it. This is the main difference between `.forEach` (which iterates over the array, but returns `undefined`) and array methods such as `.map`, `.filter`, `.reduce` that iterate, execute the callback on every item and return a modified array.

If you want to avoid a temporary array you should use `Array.map` in this case:

```
function task02(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(item, i){
    return (item > 0) ? 1 : 0;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for discovering `.map` for me and for the explanation. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone please explain to me, why this is not working?

JavaScript is [pass/call/assign by **value**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value). That implies that assigning a value to a variable won't magically change the value of another variable (or an array element).

Simpler example:

```
var foo = 42;
var bar = foo;
foo = 21;
```

`bar` will still have the value `42`.

---

In your case, assigning to `item` won't change the array element.

---

As always, if you use an unfamiliar method, [read its documentation first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: `arr = arr.forEach` return undefined that's why OP function return undefined

Comment: @Hacketo: Good catch. But even without that it wouldn't have worked.